# The inclusion relation between Ideals

Tags: ring-theory, ideals

Let the commutative ring $R$  and its element $a$ and $b$

$\langle a\rangle +\langle b\rangle =\langle a,b\rangle $

$\langle a\rangle \langle b\rangle =\langle ab\rangle $

====================================================================

## Q1) What is the inclusion relation between $\langle a\rangle $, $\langle a,b\rangle $ and $\langle ab\rangle $?

## Q2) Please tell me what point was I've wrong.

Here is my thought.

Let  $r_1$ and $r_2$  be elements of the ring $R$.

It looks obvious that $\langle ab\rangle \subseteq \langle a\rangle $ since $a\mid ab$

An the element form of $\langle a\rangle +\langle b\rangle $ and $\langle a\rangle $ are $r_1a + r_2b$ and $r_1a$ respectively.

Hence $\langle a\rangle +\langle b\rangle \subseteq \langle a\rangle $ since $0 \in R$

But $\langle a,b\rangle = \langle d\rangle $  (here $d$ means $\gcd(a,b)$)

Therefore $\langle a\rangle \subseteq \langle d\rangle $ since  $d\mid a$

So $\langle a\rangle = \langle a,b\rangle $ ?? (Surely It is a false statement.)

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: $\langle ab\rangle\subset\langle a\rangle\subset\langle a,b\rangle$ where inclusions can be proper.

Comment: Formatting tip: use \langle and \rangle instead of < and >.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things.  In arbitrary commutative rings, there may be no such thing as a $\gcd$.  Second, $\langle a, b \rangle $ is defined to be smallest ideal that contains both $a$ and $b$.  In particular, unless $b \in \langle a \rangle$, you'll have $\langle a \rangle \subsetneq \langle a, b \rangle $.  There are plenty of elements of the form $r_1a+r_2b$ that aren't multiples of $a$.

For any $r \in R, (ab)r=a(br) \in \langle a \rangle$ so $\langle ab \rangle \subseteq \langle a \rangle$ and it's obvious that $\langle a \rangle \subseteq \langle a, b \rangle$.  Some examples in $\Bbb Z$ should convince you that both inclusions can be proper.